# Every new pyenv environment that I create comes with a preinstalled list of packages shown when I do pip list

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I am currently trying to create a new virtualenvironment using `pyenv`, I have various versions of python installed using `pyenv` from 3.7.x to 3.9.x.

For creating an environment, I am doing the following:

```
$pyenv virtualenv 3.8.7 practice_django
```

which creates the environment and outputs it:

```
Looking in links: /var/folders/w1/dw5vm6p955bgmws4x53sjlym0000gn/T/tmpwltofgj8
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/practice_rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/practice_django/lib/python3.8/site-packages (20.2.3)
```

then I activate the environment using:

```
$pyenv activate practice_django
```

And check that the virtualenvironment has been created successfully and is proper by:

```
$pyenv which python
/Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/practice_django/bin/python

$python -V
Python 3.8.7 # my global python is 3.7.5

$pip -V
pip 20.2.3 from /Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/practice_django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

So, I know the environment should have been created correctly and is activated.

Now, when I do a `pip list`, I get the following (without installing any packages):

```
Package                 Version
----------------------- ------------
absl-py                 0.12.0
aio-pika                6.8.0
aiofiles                0.7.0
aiormq                  3.3.1
alembic                 1.4.3
APScheduler             3.7.0
astunparse              1.6.3
async-generator         1.10
async-timeout           3.0.1
attrs                   19.3.0
bidict                  0.21.2
boto3                   1.17.78
botocore                1.20.78
cachetools              4.2.2
certifi                 2020.12.5
cffi                    1.14.5
cloudpickle             1.6.0
colorclass              2.2.0
coloredlogs             15.0
colorhash               1.0.3
croniter                1.0.13
cryptography            3.4.7
cycler                  0.10.0
dm-tree                 0.1.6
dnspython               1.16.0
docopt                  0.6.2
fbmessenger             6.0.0
future                  0.18.2
gast                    0.3.3
gitdb                   4.0.7
GitPython               3.1.17
google-auth             1.30.0
google-auth-oauthlib    0.4.4
google-pasta            0.2.0
greenlet                1.1.0
grpcio                  1.38.0
h11                     0.9.0
h5py                    2.10.0
httpcore                0.11.1
httplib2                0.19.1
httptools               0.2.0
httpx                   0.15.4
humanfriendly           9.1
idna                    2.10
isodate                 0.6.0
jmespath                0.10.0
joblib                  0.15.1
jsonpickle              2.0.0
jsonschema              3.2.0
kafka-python            1.4.7
Keras-Preprocessing     1.1.2
kiwisolver              1.3.1
Mako                    1.1.4
Markdown                3.3.4
MarkupSafe              2.0.1
matplotlib              3.3.4
mattermostwrapper       2.2
networkx                2.5.1
numpy                   1.18.5
oauth2client            4.1.3
oauthlib                3.1.0
opt-einsum              3.3.0
packaging               20.9
pamqp                   2.3.0
pika                    1.2.0
Pillow                  8.2.0
pip                     20.2.3
prompt-toolkit          2.0.10
protobuf                3.17.0
psycopg2-binary         2.8.6
pyasn1                  0.4.8
pyasn1-modules          0.2.8
pycparser               2.20
pydot                   1.4.2
pykwalify               1.8.0
pymongo                 3.10.1
pyparsing               2.4.7
pyrsistent              0.17.3
pyTelegramBotAPI        3.7.9
python-crfsuite         0.9.7
python-dateutil         2.8.1
python-editor           1.0.4
python-engineio         4.2.0
python-socketio         5.3.0
pytz                    2021.1
PyYAML                  5.4.1
rasa                    2.6.2
rasa-sdk                2.6.0
rasa-x                  0.39.3
redis                   3.5.3
regex                   2020.9.27
requests                2.25.1
requests-oauthlib       1.3.0
requests-toolbelt       0.9.1
rfc3986                 1.5.0
rocketchat-API          1.15.0
rsa                     4.7.2
ruamel.yaml             0.16.13
ruamel.yaml.clib        0.2.2
s3transfer              0.4.2
Sanic-Cors              0.10.0.post3
Sanic-Plugins-Framework 0.9.5
scikit-learn            0.24.2
scipy                   1.6.3
sentry-sdk              0.19.5
setuptools              49.2.1
six                     1.16.0
sklearn-crfsuite        0.3.6
slackclient             2.9.3
smmap                   4.0.0
sniffio                 1.2.0
SQLAlchemy              1.3.22
tabulate                0.8.9
tensorboard             2.5.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.0
tensorflow              2.3.2
tensorflow-addons       0.12.0
tensorflow-estimator    2.3.0
tensorflow-hub          0.10.0
tensorflow-probability  0.11.1
tensorflow-text         2.3.0
termcolor               1.1.0
terminaltables          3.1.0
threadpoolctl           2.1.0
tqdm                    4.59.0
twilio                  6.50.1
typeguard               2.12.0
typing-extensions       3.10.0.0
tzlocal                 2.1
ujson                   1.35
urllib3                 1.26.4
uvloop                  0.14.0
wcwidth                 0.2.5
webexteamssdk           1.6
websockets              8.1
Werkzeug                2.0.1
wheel                   0.36.2
wrapt                   1.12.1
yarl                    1.6.3
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/practice_django/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

And when I try to do an uninstall, this happens:

```
$pip uninstall tensorflow

Found existing installation: tensorflow 2.3.2
Not uninstalling tensorflow at /Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/practice_rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages, outside environment /Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/practice_django
Can't uninstall 'tensorflow'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Which suggests, that my virtualenv `practice_django`, might be using packages from another virtualenv `practice_rasa`.

Now, if I try to import `tensorflow`, I can import it.

I want to create a clean virtualenv, with no packages installed - started to get this error today.

> P.S : Even if I create an environment with a different python version say **3.7.9**, I get the same error. I have also tried upgrading pip version - which doesn't help.

For **python3.7.9** based virtualenv, I get a similar thing on a **pip uninstall**

```
Found existing installation: websockets 8.1
Not uninstalling websockets at /Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/practice_rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages, outside environment /Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/envs/practice_django
Can't uninstall 'websockets'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

The package websockets seems to be at the virtual environment **practice_rasa**, which has python version **3.8.7**.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same issue. It seems to me like environment isolation is broken.

Comment: I have found a good solution for this, just use the installers from [python downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/), eg: [python 3.9.7 intel installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.7/python-3.9.7-macosx10.9.pkg) and install the `python version` and then use `virtualenv` along with `virtualenvwrapper`! I used to use `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` along with `deadnsakes ppa` on ubuntu and never suffered, so this is great!!! ( Only problem being that, the installers aren't available for all *bug-fix* versions, but that's not a major hassle for most programmers, tbh )

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you might be using conda and pyenv at the same time.  You may want to remove any conda configs statements from your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc files.

Comment: I am not using `conda` env, haven't got it installed either on my mac.